# How does an electromagnet work?

Tags: electromagnetism

How does an electromagnet work? I am building one, and it works, but I don't know how. Can somebody explain how the magnetic field is formed?

Comment: Hi and welcome to PSE You are expected to do your own research first and then, by all means,  ask questions on the parts you don't follow. So you could read this: https://education.jlab.org/qa/electromagnet_is.html and a search of Wikipedia will also help.

Answer (score 0):

When the electromagnet is constructed, an electrical current flows and forms a magnetic field around it. When the field is formed, circles are made around it, causing magnetism to pick up the metal like they do in junkyards.